# How to generate the custom xml headers?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm looking to fix an issue in my script which is not generating the expected xml headers and closing tag as expected. See the shared below details.
Input Payload:

```
{ 
    "result": {
        "data": [
            [
                "jane",
                "ALDANA",
                "21"
            ],
            [
                "Emma",
                "EDWARDS",
                "23"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

i'm using this script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml encoding="UTF-8", writeDeclaration=true


fun convertJsonToXml(json: Any): Any =
    if (json is Array)
        json map convertJsonToXml($)
    else if (json is Object)
        {
            (json mapObject {
                ($$): convertJsonToXml($)
            })
        }
    else
        json

---

{
    'Input:xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="csm_admin.xsd"':  {

        add: (convertJsonToXml(payload.result.data) map (item, index) -> {
            data: {
                "@firstName": item[0],
                lastName: item[1],
                age: item[2],
                
            }
        })
    }
}
```

resulted Output based on the above script:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Input:xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="csm_admin.xsd">
  <add>
    <data>
      <@firstName>jane</@firstName>
      <lastName>ALDANA</lastName>
      <age>21</age>
    </data>
  </add>
  <add>
    <data>
      <@firstName>Emma</@firstName>
      <lastName>EDWARDS</lastName>
      <age>23</age>
    </data>
  </add>
</Input:xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="csm_admin.xsd">
```

Expected xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<admin xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="csm_admin.xsd">
  <add>
    <data>
      <@firstName>jane</@firstName>
      <lastName>ALDANA</lastName>
      <age>21</age>
    </data>
  </add>
  <add>
    <data>
      <@firstName>Emma</@firstName>
      <lastName>EDWARDS</lastName>
      <age>23</age>
    </data>
  </add>
</Input>
```

as explained above the issue which i'm still facing is the headers and the closing tag which need to be fixed. i tried different approaches but could not resolve the issue.
Thanks for your inpt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi here is a code that produces exactly what you are expecting with a very simple script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
"input" @("xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"csm_admin.xsd"): {
    "add": {
        (
            payload.result.data map ((data, index) -> 
                data: {
                    "@firstName": data[0],
                    "lastName": data[1],
                    "age": data[2]
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

The way to add those attributes like "xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" under `@`

Comment: Thank you for the input. it helped a lot. I just that the first xml header is not getting generated like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: the script still does not generate the standalone=yes in declaration header as  shown in expected payload. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: That header can not be generated with DW